# Why Is the Eclipse Plugin for Day Communique not working?

Tags: java, eclipse, crx

I am trying to get Eclipse working so that it builds my war to a local instance of Day Communique.  I am using the plugin for eclipse from day: http://www.day.com/eclipse/

The .war file uses spring to start some processes.  When I install the war file using the admin function in Day, the processes start.  When I publish via eclipse, the processes do not start.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing a ton about Eclipse, Day offers a pre-packaged download of CRXDE with the new 5.3 release.  If you have access to the Daycare site you can download it.  Double click and it was working.